# Resample numpy array with interpolation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, interpolation, resampling

I am processeing 5 images in Python that have been imported as numpy arrays and have the following shape:

```
for i in range(len(S_images)):
    print(S_images[i].shape)

(1, 1524, 5500)
(1, 1524, 5499)
(1, 1524, 5500)
(1, 1524, 5499)
(1, 1525, 5499)
```

My objective is to use `S_stack = np.stack(S_images)` to stack them together but of course, due to the differences in shape I am getting the error:

```
ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape
```

What I would like is to resample the arrays to a common shape (for example, `(1, 1524, 5500)`) and at the same time select a resampling method such as Nearest neighbor.

Looking for previosu Q&A in the forum I have seen that the use of `scipy.ndimage.zoom` but that this is usually to upgrade or downgrade regular data. In my case, I just need the shapes to match to allow the stack. Any suggestion?

Would it be possible for example, to select a master array and the use it as reference where all the others would have to match its shape, and if not, a resampling method using NN would be applied?

Comment: If they're images, have you considered any of the following methods: cropping, rescaling, stretching with fixed ratio and cropping.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Cropping would solve the issue but technically it is not correct as the images are covering the same area (Satellite imagery). Wouldnt streach and resacaling be a similar methodology as applying an interpolation to get a new shape?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I have added a answer to my problem. In case you have experience, do you see it as a valid option in my case?

Comment: There's probably a more robust way to do it. (Your floating point values might have errors and produce the wrong size image.)

Comment: If it is only one eg. column i would consider simply padding [np.pad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html)

Comment: otherwise for fast rescaling look into opencv

Comment: @Mecgrad not completely convinced by `np.pad` as this creates new values for the new pixels. Since I am using satellite imagery, I don't think it would be a good approach. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq so far using a float like `1524/1525` seems to work and produces the right image size. In which context could the error take place? Isn't the division suppose to be consistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution but I am wondering if it is correct from a technical/scientific point of view. Is this good procedure to solve my issue? Practically, it is doing what I want...

```
for i in range(len(S_images)):
    if S_images[i].shape[1] !=1524:
        S_images[i] = scipy.ndimage.zoom(S_images[i], (1, 1524/1525, 1),order=0, mode='nearest')

for i in range(len(S_images)):
    if S_images[i].shape[2] !=5499:
        S_images[i] = scipy.ndimage.zoom(S_images[i], (1, 1, 5499/5500 ),order=0, mode='nearest')


for i in range(len(S_images)):
    print(S_images[i].shape)

(1, 1524, 5499)
(1, 1524, 5499)
(1, 1524, 5499)
(1, 1524, 5499)
(1, 1524, 5499)
```